# Can you assign only unmasked values using numpy.ma?

Tags: python, numpy, masked-array

Is there a way to copy values from one numpy masked array to another where ONLY the unmasked values are copied and the target values are left unchanged for masked source values? It seems like this should be handled automatically, but so far I haven't found a good way to do it. Right now I'm using ma.choose with the target region of the destination and the mask, but it really seems like there should be a better way given that the entire purpose of the masked array is to not operate on masked values automatically.

Comment: Is your target array a masked array?

Comment: You can use the mask as index expression.

Comment: That's not exactly the purpose of `ma`.  The masked values aren't removed or protected, but ignored, not used in varios calculations.  They might be replaced a fill value, or they might be compressed out.

Comment: To take full advantage of masked-arrays you have to use their own methods, or the `np.ma` functions.  Regular `numpy` functions and operations treat them as regular arrays, using all elements, the `arr.data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import ma
x = ma.array([1, 2, 3, 4], mask=[0, 1, 1, 0])
y = np.array([5, 6, 7, 8])

y[~x.mask] = x[~x.mask]
```

which gives for `y`:

```
array([1, 6, 7, 4])
```

Comment: I would never have guessed you could do that. It has some interesting performance characteristics. For an 8x8 array it's 4x as fast as ma.choose, but only 2.5x for a 2048x2048 array. Thanks.

Comment: @JustinOlbrantz For large arrays, the cost of inverting the mask twice is high. You can cache the inverted mask to avoid multiple inversions.

Comment: I did that in my test code, actually.